# how to get the list of diagnostic settings for app services using az cli

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I am trying to get list of web apps using az cli `az webapp list`. And when I try to get the diagnostic setting for the particular web app using `az monitor diagnostic-settings list --resource-group nameRG --resource id`. I dont get any information and logs and diagnostic settings are enabled for app services. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.
I am just trying to get the list of diagnostic settings for a resource. If you know better way please mention it.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried az monitor diagnostic-settings show ? it will show you the details

Comment: Hi, @user273181. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage:

```
az monitor diagnostic-settings list --resource Name --resource-group RGName --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites
```

Or:

```
az monitor diagnostic-settings list --resource ID
```

Make sure the resource id correct like this format:

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}
```

You could get the resource id by this command:

```
az webapp show --name MyWebapp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

Comment: Is there a way to update the diagnostic settings instead? I can list them just fine but there doesn't seem to be a way to update them.